# OpenMP and STL-style for

Tags: c++, stl, for-loop, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize my program with openMP. The program is using STL-iterators heavily. It is [said](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/11/09/openmp-30-and-iterators/) that openMP 3.0 can deal with this:

```
std::vector<int> N(2*N_max+1);

std::vector<int>::const_iterator n,m;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (n=N.begin(); n!=N.end(); ++n){
     //Task to be in parallel
};
```

But I got the following error:

```
error: invalid controlling predicate
```

I'm using gcc 4.5.0, (openMP3 implemented in 4.4.0) and my build string is:

```
g++  -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -MMD -MP
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard OpenMP doesn't bear with C++ iterators in general.  The standard requires iterators to be random access iterators with constant time for random access.  It also only permits `<` and `<=` or `>` and `>=` in test expressions of for loops, but not `!=`.

If you are using iterators and STL heavily, you might be better off with [Thread building blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

Comment: for (n=N.begin(); n<N.end(); ++n) Solves the problem. Performance not tested, but I guess this sould not affect it. Of course only std::vector and friends are supported.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the OpenMP V3.0 spec didn't include "!=" as part of the legal syntax for a canonical for loop.  However, if you have access to a recent Intel compiler they allowed it as an extension.